# failed to execute script myfile.py using pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller, pystray

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import datetime
import os
import pystray
from pystray import MenuItem as item
import win32com.client
import PIL.Image as Image
```

my import list

```
pyinstaller --noconsole create_tray.py
76 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0.dev0
76 INFO: Python: 3.8.2
76 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
77 INFO: wrote C:\Users\jamoz\Desktop\PythonWorkSpace\record_time\create_tray.spec
78 INFO: UPX is not available.
84 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\jamoz\\Desktop\\PythonWorkSpace\\record_time',
 'C:\\Users\\jamoz\\Desktop\\PythonWorkSpace\\record_time']
89 INFO: checking Analysis
90 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
90 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
92 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
102 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2474 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
2476 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\python38\\lib'
5412 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
5557 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
5578 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\python38\python.exe
5652 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\jamoz\Desktop\PythonWorkSpace\record_time\create_tray.py
5773 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
6879 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
6880 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
7896 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook setuptools.extern.six.moves from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
8977 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
9254 INFO: Processing module hooks...
9254 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9256 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9337 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9380 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9709 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9710 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
9713 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
9713 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
9713 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
9715 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module PIL.ImageQt
9715 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module PIL.ImageQt
9716 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'PySide'
9716 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'PyQt4'
9716 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9717 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
9718 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
9718 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10284 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
10285 INFO: Excluding import '__main__'
10286 INFO:   Removing import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
10287 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10289 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10415 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
10416 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10484 WARNING: Unable to find Qt5 translations C:/python38/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/translations\qtbase_*.qm. These translations were not packaged.
10484 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10616 WARNING: Unable to find Qt5 translations C:/python38/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/translations\qtbase_*.qm. These translations were not packaged.
10619 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
10944 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11271 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11812 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11813 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11871 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11872 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11873 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
11874 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
12029 INFO: checking Tree
12029 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
12030 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
12092 INFO: checking Tree
12093 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
12096 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
12130 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
12182 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
12189 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
12192 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
12194 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
12196 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
12208 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
12728 INFO: Looking for eggs
12728 INFO: Using Python library c:\python38\python38.dll
12729 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
12735 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\jamoz\Desktop\PythonWorkSpace\record_time\build\create_tray\warn-create_tray.txt
12826 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\jamoz\Desktop\PythonWorkSpace\record_time\build\create_tray\xref-create_tray.html
12861 INFO: checking PYZ
12862 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
12863 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\jamoz\Desktop\PythonWorkSpace\record_time\build\create_tray\PYZ-00.pyz
14200 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\jamoz\Desktop\PythonWorkSpace\record_time\build\create_tray\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
14215 INFO: checking PKG
14216 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
14217 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
14245 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
14248 INFO: Bootloader c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\runw.exe
14250 INFO: checking EXE
14251 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
14251 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
14255 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\jamoz\Desktop\PythonWorkSpace\record_time\build\create_tray\create_tray.exe
14269 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

and this is pyinstaller log

how can i do?

Comment: Use pyinstaller to pack it again without `-w` to see the error info.

Comment: what error comes while the script is running?

Comment: not have error in script
and console log                                                                             
     {
Traceback (most recent call all last):
File "create_tray.py", line 6, in <module>
File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "pystray\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
Fiile "pystray\__init__.py", line 44, in backend
ImportError: this paltform is not supported : no module named 'pystray._win32'
Failed to execute script create_tray
}
Thank you for comment

Comment: try to add --hidden-import pystray._win32 to your build command

Answer (score 3):

I have got the same issue. If you are using a windows platform, just try to `import pystray` like below :

```py
from pystray._base import MenuItem as item
import pystray._win32
```

It solved my problem and hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, following command resolves this issue.

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import 'pystray._win32' --noconsole 'create_tray.py'
```